# How do I handle www subdomain in a production instance of Flask

Tags: python, flask

I use an Apache server for production with Flask as a WSGI app.

My Apache VirtualHost conf looks like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName mysite.com
 ServerAlias www.mysite.com
 ...
</VirtualHost>
```

And my /etc/hosts file looks like this

```
200.110.100.11  mysite.com
200.110.100.11  www.mysite.com
```

I realized yesterday that my site was storing 2 different sessions for the naked domain and the www subdomain. So the user was logged out of www.mysite.com even if he was logged into mysite.com

After reading Flask docs, I figured that I had to set the `SERVER_NAME` config value and map the hosts file accordingly. So I set the `SERVER_NAME` config to mysite.com. But now I have a bigger problem. www.mysite.com/ started showing 404 after I set this value. However it is the custom 404 page I have set in my app, which means that the request is reaching my app, but it is not able to find a route. However mysite.com/ continues to work fine.

I chanced upon this thread https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/issues/555 and tried adding the line app.url_map.default_subdomain = 'www' to my init module and it only resulted in mysite.com getting a 404 now.

What am I missing here? I am not using Blueprints for my views as yet.

Comment: Is it necessary to serve the site on both www and non-www domains? You can just redirect either of these to the other easily using apache.

Comment: Thanks. I have done that now.